# Karabiner elements delete a line

Tags: karabiner

I'm new to Karabiner on Mac and I'm trying to map left_option + e to deleting a line.

I know this involves defining the following keystrokes for left_command + e: left_command + shift + left_arrow + backspace_or_delete, but I don't know how to input it to the json file

Answer (score 2):

Here I created code that moves cursor to the beginning of the line and then deletes it.

`{
    "description": "Delete line",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "e",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": ["left_option"]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "a",
                    "modifiers": ["left_control"]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "k",
                    "modifiers": ["left_control"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}`